# Ping not working as expected

Tags: linux, networking, bash, ping, raspberry-pi

This is kind of a follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34476932) question.

My goal in the end is to use my Raspberry Pi 1 Model B to log whenever the Internet connection goes down, and for how long.

I tried doing that with the following command:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 |  while read line; do echo "$(date): $line"; done | grep --line-buffered time= | tee -a googleping
```

The above command works on a Ubuntu 15.10 Server and also my MacBook Air with OS X 10.11.2. So I thought I could just use the same on the Pi. But then the first error showed up.

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8

ping: icmp open socket: Operation not permitted
```

To get around that I then started ping as super user:

```
$ sudo ping 8.8.8.8

PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=12.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=12.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=13.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=58 time=12.6 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 12.640/12.787/13.002/0.171 ms
```

Now you would think this solves my problem but no, after this there is another problem I noticed. The `ping`command on the Pi doesn't output request timeouts. So when a package is timed out the Pi just resends it where I would expect a message like that:

```
Request timeout for icmp_seq 39
```

But what I get is just nothing, it apparently just resends the package until it gets an answer, but the lost packages show up in the summary at the end:

```
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
168 packets transmitted, 131 received, 22% packet loss, time 167191ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 12.082/13.099/32.888/2.322 ms
```

The last output before the summary is the following:

```
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=150 ttl=58 time=12.5 ms
```

Which shows that only 151 different `icmp_sequences` were sent, and the dropped ones just resend over and over again.

I should also add, that I ping my local router `192.168.2.1` in addition to google `8.8.8.8` to see if it is the connection to the router, or really the connection to google.

The following results in the same output on both systems:

```
$ ping -V

ping utility, iputils-s20121221
```

After some looking around I found an option in the man page for ping on the Pi that somewhat does what I want:

```
$ man ping

[...]
-O     Report  outstanding  ICMP  ECHO  reply  before  sending next packet.
       This is useful together with the timestamp -D to log output to a 
       diagnostic  file  and  search  for missing answers.
[...]
```

That produces the following output if a package is too slow:

```
no answer yet for icmp_seq=499
```

But if my understanding is correct then this is different in the way that the `ping` command on ubuntu only outputs the message if the answer is not received before the timeout, even if another ping package was send before the answer received. The `ping` command on my Pi prints the message also out when the answer will be revived after the message is received.

So why is this different on a Pi than on a Ubuntu server?
How can I achieve my goal?

Question also posted on [raspberrypi.stackexchange.com](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/40141/5538).

Comment: The correct link to the crosspost on Rpi.SE is http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/40141/5538

Comment: Completly rewrote the question to give more information in a better organized way.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the following command

```
 sudo chmod u+s `which ping`
```

will make `ping` work also for a non-su user.

Second, you can cure your problem with the following option,

```
ping -c 1 -W 1 192.168.0.1
```

The first option sends out a single packet, the second establishes a timeout period beyond which a packet is declared missing, and an error message is printed. For instance,

```
$ ping -c1 www.nytimes.com
  PING www.gtm.nytimes.com (170.149.161.130) 56(84) bytes of data.
  ^C
  --- www.gtm.nytimes.com ping statistics ---
  1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms

 $ ping -c1 -W 1 www.nytimes.com
   PING www.gtm.nytimes.com (170.149.161.130) 56(84) bytes of data.

   --- www.gtm.nytimes.com ping statistics ---
   1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

As you can see, in the first case (without the `-W 1` option) `ping` was waiting for a reply and only my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> halted the wait, with no output produced. But in the second case, with the `-W 1` (= Wait for 1 second, then give up) an error message was promptly produced.

But third, I suggest you use `mtr` (=*My TraceRoute*), available from the repos. You might use something like

```
mtr -c 1 -r 8.8.8.8
```

The first option sends 1 packet, the `-r` option prints a report at the end of the cycle, and the command tries to contact all nodes between your pc and Google's DNS (8.8.8.8). The advantage of doing this is that you would get a trace of where, exactly, your connection breaks down, so that you may know whether this takes place inside your LAN or outside it, in which case you may have to complain to your ISP.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer! But I want to just log it when the connection to google is not available and not also every time the connection is available. And I forgot to mention is my question that I ping my router as well as google to see if the local connection is there, since the pi is directly attached to the local router. (I'm going to add that now)

Comment: @usbpc102  If you only want to log under certain conditions, you may very well script the above.

Comment: Okay, yea, that will let me achieve my goal, but I still want to know why ping behaves different on the pi than anywhere else. ;)